# Output and Input mismatch bubble sort algorithm

Tags: c#

Trying to learn bubble sort algorithm, I have the following input **1, 9, 5, 4, 2**

```
    var arr = new int[] { 1, 9, 5, 4, 2 };

    var rightVal = 0;
    var leftVal = 0;
    var leftIndex = 0;


    for (int i = arr.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {

        var val = arr[i];
        for (int j = i; j >= 0; j--)
        {
            if (j > 0)
            {
                leftIndex = j - 1;
            }
            else if (j == 0)
            {
                leftIndex = 0;
            }

            leftVal = arr[leftIndex];


            if (val < leftVal)
            {

                arr[j] = leftVal;
                arr[j - 1] = val;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this produces an output of **1,2,5,9,4** what am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: [Navigating through Code using the Step Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)

Comment: I agree with that comment recommending your navigate through your code with the debugger. What's happening is, you swap the 4 and 2 in the first step of the loop and then never skip over the 4 because it got swapped. Step through the debugger and watch your 4 big variables: `val`, `j`, `left index`, and `leftVal`

Comment: That is what I was doing, just forgetting to update the value of val once moving. Ended up with exactly the same answer as below :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
var arr = new int[] { 1, 9, 5, 4, 2 };

var leftVal = 0;

for (int i = arr.Length - 1; i >= 1; i--)
{
    var val = arr[i];
    for (int j = i-1; j >= 0; j--)
    {
        leftVal = arr[j];
        if (val < leftVal)
        {
            arr[i] = leftVal;
            arr[j] = val;
            val = leftVal;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, I just ended up doing this. Thanks